# Coan gives "expands to nothing within expression" with defined symbol

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, undefined, symbols

I am trying to use [coan](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/) to generate a clean version of a codebase but it creashes on the first source code fine on the first definition, using:

```
coan source -DNON_SMS --filter c,h --recurse --replace test -V
```

I get:

```
coan: progress 0x00101: Processing file (1) 
"D:\Documents\Downloads\test\cli.c"
coan: D:\Documents\Downloads\test\cli.c: line 53: error 0x00816: "NON_SMS" expands to nothing within expression, in "#if ( NON_SMS ) /* Non-SMS compile */"
coan: progress 0x02101: Completed with errors, exit code 0x04
coan: info 0x02201: 1 out of 41 input files were reached; 40 files were not reached
coan: info 0x02202: 0 out of 1 files reached were valid; 1 were abandoned due to parse errors
```

but the code works properly on MSVS and this statement is actually very simple:

```
#if       ( NON_SMS )                   /*  Non-SMS compile  */

#include  <stdlib.h>                    /*  Standard library definitions   */
#include  <string.h>                    /*  String related definitions     */

#else
```

This is on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Is this C or C++?  There is a difference between the languages.  For example, C++ has `std::string` and C doesn't.  In C, I can have a variable called "class".  Adjust your tags accordingly.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews this is both applicable to C and C++ as coan process both with the same interface.

Comment: Try `-DNON_SMS=1` or `-DNON_SMS=0`. The code is checking the value, not just whether it's defined.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar that solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coan expects that when the code is like

```
#if (MACRO)
```

that `MACRO` will have a value -- if you just wanted to test whether the macro is defined, you would have written

```
#ifdef MACRO
```

So you need to give `NON_SMS` a value, e.g.

```
coan source -DNON_SMS=1 --filter c,h --recurse --replace test -V
```

Comment: In gcc and other common compilers, `-DNON_SMS` actually means `-DNON_SMS=1`. I don't know anything about "coan" but if it gives subtly different meaning to `-D` then this is somewhat confusing to its users.